# How to break a "FOR" without touching the "IF" in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, types

I use an translator, maybe because of this it will be a little difficult to understand me, but I will try to express the problem clearly.

The program is written in C#, with the help of the "for" loop, it is added that until the password is entered correctly, the "for" loop will not stop, but if it is entered correctly, it will show an inscription with a choice. Example:
Enter password: 12345 //if the password is correct, it will show this inscription ↓

Code for GTA San Andreas - enter a number to view the list of codes:
1 - Codes for weapons
2 - Codes for cars.
3 - Cheats for health, armor and money
Your choice: 2

### You have selected codes for cars:

### AIWPRTON - Rhino tank
PDNEJOH-Hotring Racer 73
AGBDLCID-Monster

Enter Password: // this is where the error is, I don't want the user to re-enter the password, but I want it to say "Your choice:" instead of this inscription

Below is the code, you can check it out, thanks in advance to everyone!

SCRIPT ↓

```
            string password = "12345";
            string userInput;
            string userChoice;
            int triesCount = 5;


            
            for (int i = 0; i < triesCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter password: ");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput == password)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCode for GTA San Andreas - enter a number to view the list of codes:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1 - Codes for weapons");
                    Console.WriteLine("2 - Codes for cars");
                    Console.WriteLine("3 - Cheats for health, armor and money");
                    Console.Write("Your choice: ");
                    userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                    switch (userChoice)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("LXGIWYL - набор оружия №1 для любителей (кастет, бита, пистолет 9mm, дробовик, micro SMG, AK-47, винтовка, ракетница, коктейль Молотова, баллончик с краской).");
                            Console.WriteLine("KJKSZPJ - набор оружия №2 для профессионалов (нож, пистолет Desert Eagle, обрез (дробовик Sawn-off), Tec-9, M4, снайперская винтовка, огнетушитель, огнемет, гранаты).");
                            Console.WriteLine("UZUMYMW - набор оружия №3 для психов (бензопила, пистолет с глушителем, боевой дробовик (Combat shotgun), MP5, M4, Stinger, взрывчатка с дистанционным пультом).");
                            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("AIWPRTON - танк Rhino");
                            Console.WriteLine("PDNEJOH - Hotring Racer 73");
                            Console.WriteLine("AGBDLCID - Monster");
                            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("HESOYAM  - полное здоровье, броня и $250.000.");
                            Console.WriteLine("BAGUVIX - бесконечное здоровье с защитой от пуль, падения.");
                            Console.WriteLine("MUNASEF - уровень адреналина.");
                            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWrong password entered.");
                    Console.WriteLine($"you have left {triesCount - (i + 1)} attempts.\n");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

I can’t understand the logic, perhaps there is not enough knowledge in programming, or I know, I just can’t combine

Comment: You just need to add a _break_ statement as the last line inside the code block executed when the password is correct

Comment: While the whole control flow seems a bit strange to me (ie I'd check the password first, and once the user entered the correct password continue with the program logic) , you can just add an additional `break;` *after* your `switch {...}` so the loop will end ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `bool` variable to track if the password is correct. Once a user is verified, then they can see the main block:

```
string password = "12345";
string userInput;
string userChoice;
int triesCount = 5;
bool isVerified=false;


for (int i = 0; i < triesCount; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter password: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userInput == password)
    {
        isVerified=true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWrong password entered.");
        Console.WriteLine($"you have left {triesCount - (i + 1)} attempts.\n");
    }
}

if(isVerified)
{
        Console.WriteLine("\nCode for GTA San Andreas - enter a number to view the list of codes:");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Codes for weapons");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Codes for cars");
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Cheats for health, armor and money");
        Console.Write("Your choice: ");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("LXGIWYL - ????? ?????? ?1 ??? ????????? (??????, ????, ???????? 9mm, ????????, micro SMG, AK-47, ????????, ?????????, ???????? ????????, ????????? ? ???????).");
                Console.WriteLine("KJKSZPJ - ????? ?????? ?2 ??? ?????????????? (???, ???????? Desert Eagle, ????? (???????? Sawn-off), Tec-9, M4, ??????????? ????????, ????????????, ???????, ???????).");
                Console.WriteLine("UZUMYMW - ????? ?????? ?3 ??? ?????? (?????????, ???????? ? ??????????, ?????? ???????? (Combat shotgun), MP5, M4, Stinger, ?????????? ? ????????????? ???????).");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                break;
            case "2":
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("AIWPRTON - ???? Rhino");
                Console.WriteLine("PDNEJOH - Hotring Racer 73");
                Console.WriteLine("AGBDLCID - Monster");
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                break;
            case "3":
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("HESOYAM  - ?????? ????????, ????? ? $250.000.");
                Console.WriteLine("BAGUVIX - ??????????? ???????? ? ??????? ?? ????, ???????.");
                Console.WriteLine("MUNASEF - ??????? ??????????.");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
                break;
        }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *extracting a method*, `Login` in our case to split a complex routine into two simpler ones:

1. Login
2. Business logic (codes for GTA)

So we start from `Login`:

```
private const int MaxAttemptsToLogin = 5;

private static bool Login(int maxAttempts = MaxAttemptsToLogin) {
  //TODO: naive code; a better version is to compare hashes (user input and password)
  const string password = "12345";

  for (int attempt = 0; attempt < MaxAttemptsToLogin; ++attempt) {
    Console.Write("Enter password: ");

    if (password == Console.ReadLine()) 
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Then you can use it as follow

```
// Do nothing and exit the program if user is not logged in
if (!Login())
  return;

// From now on, user is properly logged

while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Code for GTA San Andreas - enter a number to view the list of codes:");
  Console.WriteLine("1 - Codes for weapons");
  Console.WriteLine("2 - Codes for cars");
  Console.WriteLine("3 - Cheats for health, armor and money");
  Console.WriteLine("q - For quit");

  userChoice = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

  if ("q".Equals(userChoice, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    break;

  //TODO: Put your business logic here
}
```